# How can I use a GitHub URL as a dependency in a package.json to satisfy a peer dependency?

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies

I have two dependencies: `foo` and `foo-extras`.

`foo-extras` has the peer dependency of `"foo": ">=2.0 <4"`.

I've encountered a bug in `foo`. I've reported it and created a pull request fixing it. But I cannot wait for the `foo` developers to review and accept it so, until them, I wanted to just use my fork directly with `"foo": "myself/foo"`.

This results in the error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: my-project@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: foo@undefined
npm ERR! node_modules/foo
npm ERR!   foo@"myself/foo" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer foo@">=2.0 <4" from foo-extras@1.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/foo-extras
npm ERR!   foo-extras@"1.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /root/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

Comment: The underlying issue appears to be that by using a GitHub URL NPM interprets the dependency as having an `undefined` version. If I could figure out how to give it a version this would be fixed.